# vscodeのc++のデバッグで統合ターミナルからcinをしたいができない

Tags: c++, vscode

VSCodeのデバッグで**統合ターミナルから**cinで入力を受け取りたいのですが、うまくいきません

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

このコードをVSCodeでF5キーを押してデバッグを開始すると、デバッガが起動してから以下のようなコマンド(?)がでてそこから反応がなくなり、中止するしかなくなります
もちろんキー入力も不可能です

```
C:\hoge> cmd /C "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.8.0\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-oqrzmztc.o1u --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-t2xl2cuv.3gu --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-yrcgm1xw.lco --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-s1bsojac.fmy --dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
```

launch.jsonは以下のようになっています

```
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - アクティブ ファイルのビルドとデバッグ",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "gdb の再フォーマットを有効にする",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "逆アセンブリ フレーバーを Intel に設定",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe アクティブなファイルのビルド"
        }
    ]
}
```

`"externalConsole": true`もすでに試して動作しましたが、プログラムと外部コンソールがすぐに終了して出力を確認できないなど、不都合が多かったので統合ターミナルからの入力方法を模索しています

Comment: いずれも解決していませんが、これらの記事が同様の話題を扱っていそうです。[How can I read from stdin using the integrated Visual Studio Code terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64053110/9014308), [\[Windows\] cppdbg debugger Unable to Use Integrated Terminal with mingw #5497](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5497), [C++ Terminal Not Working in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67001664/9014308), [How to run programs in Visual Studio Code integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70443034/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。

既存のコンパイラを消して、コンパイラを [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) に変更したらできるようになりました。
(vscodeのc/c++の拡張機能やlaunch.jsonのファイルなどは念の為一度消して入れ直しました)